# Redirect request from localhost to webserver

Tags: websocket, localhost, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

I wrote an *app.js* that exchanges data with an existing web server using *Socket.io* and *Axios*. If the script is launched in an editor (*VS Code* / *WebStorm*), it runs without problems.

Now I have tried to carry out the app.js through *Chrome*.

- create *index.html*
- integrate *app.js* as a script
- bundle with *webpack*
- overwrite the CORS with a *head-editor*
- call *index.html*

The problem is that the *Request URL* is always reset to `http://localhost/65432/.../app.js` (*WebStorm*) or `http://localhost/3000/.../app.js` (*VS Code*).
If I overwrite the Request URL with the *head-editor*, no websocket connection is established.

My questions:

1. Why is the Request URL on `http://localhost/`?
2. How do I connect to the web server?